# Changing Style with click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make a to do list app. When i click a span with class "check" then i want to apply a style. Then the class of the span will change to "uncheck". When click the uncheck then the previous style will restore. Here is the html and jquery what i have done so far.

**Problem:** Problem is when i first click the span it works The "uncheck" class get removed and "check" class get added. Then the second part not works. I suspect the second part don't working because the "check" class is not in the dom when document.ready() is runs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
         <div class="note-body">
                <ol>
                    <li>M2u category shown. M2u category shown M2u category shown M2u category shown.
                        <span title="Delete" class="delete"></span>
                        <span title="Task Done!" class="done"></span>
                        <span class="handle"></span>
                        <span class="handle"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>M2u category shown</li>
                    <li>M2u category shown</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $('.note-body ol li span.check').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('uncheck').removeClass('check');

            $(this).parent().css({'text-decoration':'line-through', 'color':'#5b382e'});

    });

   $('.note-body ol li span.uncheck').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('check').removeClass('uncheck');

            $(this).parent().css({'text-decoration':'none', 'color':'#5b382e'});

});
```

---

**RESOLVED:**

Had to use the `live();` because i am adding dom dynamically. Here is the final code (placed the styles in classes):

```
$('.note-body ol li span.check').live('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('uncheck').removeClass('check');
            $(this).parent().addClass('task-done').removeClass('task-notdone');
    });

   $('.note-body ol li span.uncheck').live('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('check').removeClass('uncheck');
            $(this).parent().addClass('task-notdone').removeClass('task-done');
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. Since the 'uncheck' class is dynamically added to the DOM, you need to use the [jQuery live API](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Try this:

```
   $('.note-body ol li span.uncheck').live('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass('check').removeClass('uncheck');

            $(this).parent().css({'text-decoration':'none', 'color':'#5b382e'});

});
```

Comment: You can also use just one callback and check if the clicked element has a certain class: `if($(this).hasClass('check')) {...} else {...}`

Comment: thanks! Great help. Did not knew about the `live();`  :) my bad!

Answer (score 1):

use jquery live or delegate as they are added runtime

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need an `uncheck` class? Are there three states `check`, `uncheck` and 'nothing'? Getting rid of the `uncheck` class you could simplify your code.

I would do:

```
$('.note-body .some_other_identifier').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('check');
});
```

Adding

```
.some_other_identifier {'text-decoration':'line-through'; 'color':'#5b382e'; }
.check .some_other_identifier { 'text-decoration':'none'; 'color':'#5b382e'; }
```

to your css.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to have a uncheck class because that might help when i go with the database and php stuff. Surely will remove it if not needed in the end. Thanks for your advice!